# Recovering Data

Tags: data-recovery

So a couple weeks back, I accidentally installed Ubuntu over Windows. I've been reading about different programs that can recover data. I was wondering if it's possible to use one of those programs to recover the lost files? Would it be better to leave it on Ubuntu and use a program on Ubuntu or to switch it back to Windows and use a program on there? Also, what's the best program?

Thanks,
RPT

Comment: Find an application, like OnTrack easy recovery and they typically have a boot disk and a trial to see what you'll find.  You're out nothing for trying.

Comment: I rolled back your follow-up question because the question-and-answer format of AskUbuntu is unsuitable for this type of growing question scope. What would we do with previously correct answers that become obsolete after the change of scope? If you have a new or follow-up question please [open a new question](/questions/ask) and may refer to the previous question in it. You can also send me a notification to draw my attention to it and I'll try to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult since the disk was overwriten by Ubuntu, but maybe using a 3rd party tool from outside Ubuntu, like GetDataBack: http://www.get-databack.com/ntfs-drive.html

or search Hiren's Boot disk utility that include some.

In my experience, I have recovered files after long waits of scanning with that tools.
If those programs find something, is very probable you'll lost directory structure and filenames but will better than nothing.

Comment: Alright thanks so much, I'll try that tomorrow

Comment: Hiren's Boot CD is a collection of pirated software, not a good recommendation actually. :)