# Recovering data in increments for a large lost partition?

Tags: data-recovery, file-sharing, transfer

This post relates to this other question of mine: [Recovering Data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852509/recovering-data?noredirect=1#comment1312080_852509)

I'm finding a partition on TestDisk, but it's about 300 GB and I don't have an external hard drive on hand.

- Is it possible to put pieces of the recovered data on a 16 GB flash drive, then bring it over to my other laptop? (The laptop has a terabyte hard drive so storage is not an issue)

  Or is there anything else I can do, such as uploading the recovery to the cloud?

Thanks!

Comment: @user.dz Does the NFS share have to be on Ubuntu or Windows? I have both installed on the second PC.

Comment: @user.dz How do I setup an nfs share and then connect to it?

Comment: Follow this one for Ubuntu http://tecadmin.net/how-to-configure-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu/

Comment: What about hosting it on windows and having Ubuntu client?

Comment: I have tried the freenfs.exe in win7 but it got an error on ubuntu client about permissions. I'm not super good in windows neither is on-topic here, you better ask in https://superuser.com/

Comment: @user.dz that looks like a good answer. You might consider expanding the instructions a bit and writing a full answer instead of comments. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, thank you for remind, I was in doubt about this.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options but It too broad to pass or expend all of them. Our refrence here is this simple recover method explained in:

[Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775579/recovering-broken-or-deleted-ntfs-partitions)

It is always recommended to make `dd` or `ddrescue` image of the partition, then run `testdisk`/`photorec` through the image. Which means 02x 300GB free space is needed.

- Both `dd`/`ddrescue` support start position and size. So you can read chunks one by one, copy to flash disk then merge them on PC2.

  **`man dd`**

  ```
     count_bytes
            treat 'count=N' as a byte count (iflag only)

     skip_bytes
            treat 'skip=N' as a byte count (iflag only)

     seek_bytes
            treat 'seek=N' as a byte count (oflag only)
  ```

  The disadvantage is that you have 20 rounds (300GB/15GB) of copy/paste each with a chunk of 15GB.
- Setup an NFS share on PC2 and mount it on PC1, Recommended Ethernet cable connection instead of WiFi for quick transfer.

  **Reference:** [Ubuntu Server Guide: Network File System (NFS)](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/network-file-system.html)

  **PC2:** Server

  1. Install NFS server

     ```
     sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
     ```
  2. Setup share folder

     ```
     sudo nano /etc/exports

     /media/<username>/<partition-name>/<shared-folder>    *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
     ```
  3. Start the NFS service

     ```
     sudo service nfs-kernel-server start
     ```

  **PC1:** Client

  1. Install NSF client tools

     ```
     sudo apt-get install nfs-common
     ```
  2. Mount the shared folder

     ```
     sudo mkdir /mnt/pc2-nfs
     sudo chown <username> <username> /mnt/pc2-nfs
     sudo mount <pc2-ip>:/media/<username>/<partition-name>/<shared-folder>  /mnt/pc2-nfs
     ```